# how i can make a custom popup menu is accessible

Tags: java, android, accessibility

there is  a custom popup menu. The problem is that when. the menu  is opened "talkback" users can focus not only on the menu items but also on  other elements of current  activity 
i try to set no_important_for_accessibility for other elements but may be there is an alternative way?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example! See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You should add tabindex="0" or tabindex="1" for Screenreaders. 
But add any example for it please like Константин Галиахметов tell here.